# How to dynamically call Classes via DexClassLoader in ANdroid

Tags: java, android, dynamic-class-loaders, dexclassloader

My app is called **MyNiceApp**. MyNiceApp is mostly just a core that loads a **CORE** view which gets populated by other plugins which the user downloads as wishes. I'm thinking that Android will install MyNiceApp in a folder called *MyNiceApp*, just as linux would default to **opt/MyNiceApp** or Windows to **Program Files/MyNiceApp**. I'm thinking it would be better organized if I had a folder created under *MyNiceApp/plugins*, then have **DexClassLoader** crawl *MyNiceApp/plugins* for downloaded plugins, then I could call my Class implementations, and dynamically load the plugin views to the *core* view at runtime.

**QUESTIONS**

1. How can I create this folder *(MyNiceApp/plugins)* when the app gets installed,
2. How can DexClassLoader be pointed to *MyNiceApp/plugins* folder,
3. Is this the best approach for this type of situation

Comment: If you plan on distributing through the Play Store, please discuss your plans with an attorney first. Quoting [the guidelines](https://play.google.com/about/privacy-security/malicious-behavior/), "Apps or SDKs that download executable code, such as dex files or native code, from a source other than Google Play" are "explicitly prohibited". "I'm thinking that Android will install MyNiceApp in a folder called MyNiceApp" -- um, no.

Comment: Thank's for the reply @CommonsWare. I'm looking at a way to load the plugins at a central place where I could crawl and load them all. What would be the best approach?

Comment: Distribute the plugins as APKs, and communicate with them using IPC. Security on `DexClassLoader`-based techniques ranges from so-so to craptastic, which is why Google has banned them.